# how to change indent of the brace after MACRO in vim

Tags: c, vim, clang-format

I use 'clang-format 9.0' to auto-format c code by plug vim-clang-format in vim.

the following is my settings of vim-clang-format,  it is based on clang-format.

```
 24     " for llvm , ref  http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html
 25     let g:clang_format#code_style='llvm'
 26     let g:clang_format#style_options = {}
 27     let g:clang_format#style_options.TabWidth = 4
 28     let g:clang_format#style_options.UseTab = 'Never'
 29     let g:clang_format#style_options.IndentWidth = 4
 30     let g:clang_format#style_options.IndentPPDirectives = 'BeforeHash'
 31     let g:clang_format#style_options.AccessModifierOffset = -4
 32     let g:clang_format#style_options.BreakBeforeBraces = 'Allman'
 33     let g:clang_format#style_options.AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine = 'false'
 34     let g:clang_format#style_options.IndentCaseLabels = 'true'
 35     let g:clang_format#style_options.AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine = 'false'
 36     let g:clang_format#style_options.AlignConsecutiveDeclarations = 'true'
 37     let g:clang_format#style_options.AlignConsecutiveMacros = 'true'
 38     let g:clang_format#style_options.AlignTrailingComments = 'true'
 39     let g:clang_format#style_options.BinPackArguments = 'false'
 40     let g:clang_format#style_options.BinPackParameters = 'false'
 41     let g:clang_format#style_options.ColumnLimit = '80'
 42     let g:clang_format#style_options.Standard = 'C++11'
 43     let g:clang_format#style_options.AlignEscapedNewlines = 'Right'
 44     let g:clang_format#style_options.AlignConsecutiveAssignments = 'true'
```

the problem is the following code:
my expected:

```c
#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)                                                   \
{                                                                              \
    &name, &name                                                               \
}

if (abc == 1)
{

}
```

but the result is the following :

```c
#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)                                                   \
    {                                                                          \
        &name, &name                                                           \
    }

if (abc == 1)
{

}
```

how to config it ?